# getopt not accepting argument value starting with hyphen -

Tags: bash, getopt

My script has an option `o`, which should accept argument as value, as below

```
./script -o '-p 2' ls
```

but getopt is not allowing, giving an error

```
Unrecognized option '-p 2'
```

code snippet:

```
ARGS=$(getopt -a -n $0 -o o::h -- "$@")
   eval set -- "$ARGS"
   while true
   do
     case "$1" in
      -o) opt="$2"; echo "options: $2"; shift; shift;;
      -h) echo "$usage"; exit 0;;
      --) cmd="$2"; shift; break;;
     esac
   done
```

How can I pass arguments as value to script?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts of your script.

Comment: try `./script -o -- '-p 2'`?

Comment: Though it is  not giving error, but unable to get value into `opt` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getopts` following a [tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "o:h" opt; do
   case $opt in
      o) option="$OPTARG"; echo "options: $option";;
      h) echo "$usage"; exit 0;;
   esac
done
cmd="${@: -1}" # Warning: Get the last argument, even if it doesn't exist !
```

Answer (score 0):

getopt is buggy and obsolete, please try `getopts`.