# How to optimize the following validations?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to perform some validations. I tried making multiple ifs in order to verify if every parameter is appropriately stored. 
I would like to know if this a good way to proceed, or if there is another strategy to achieve this.  Another problem of this implementation is that when the user doesn't type all the parameters, my script only prints the first if which is this:

```
Missing supplierCode
```

My complete code looks like this. I would like to appreciate any idea or suggestion to make a better implementation.

```
#!/bin/bash
function menu () {
        while (($# >= 1))
        do
        key="$1"
        case $key in
                --supplierCode)
                supplier_code=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --vanID)
                van_id=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --vanIDp)
                van_idp=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --tgoID)
                tgo_id=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --tgoIDp)
                tgo_idp=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --company_name)
                company_name=$2

                shift
                ;;
                --ediFact)
                file_type=E
                ;;
                --webEdi)
                file_type=P
                ;;
                --PV)
                pv=1
                ;;
                --PT)
                pt=1
                ;;
                --help)

                exit
                ;;
        esac
        shift
        done
}
function error () {
        #Validations:
    if [ -z "$supplier_code" ]
        then
                echo "Missing supplierCode"
                exit 1
        fi

    if [ -z "$van_id" ]
        then
                echo "Missing vanID"
                exit 1
        fi
    if [ -z "$van_idp" ]
        then
                echo "Missing vanIDp"
                exit 1
        fi
    if [ -z "$tgo_id" ]
        then
                echo "Missing tgoID"
                exit 1
        fi
    if [ -z "$tgo_idp" ]
        then
                echo "Missing tgoIDp"
                exit 1
        fi
    if [ -z "$company_name" ]
        then
                echo "Missing company_name"
                exit 1
        fi
    if [ -z "$file_type" ]
        then
                echo "Missing ediFact or webEdi"
                exit 1
        fi
     if [ "$pv" -eq "0" ] && [ "$pt" -eq "0" ]
        then
                echo "Error: You have to use at least one of those flags --PV , --PT "
                exit 1
    fi

}
menu "$@"
error
```

Comment: Still trying to grok your question ;-) meanwhile, you should add a `p` so you do not ignore `$van_idp` in the error function. Then I would remove the noise of the echo statements in the menu function. When you do this online bash linters like shellcheck.net are ok with your script. Now to the real question ... ah simple. Remove the exit calls in the if check sections ... cf. my answer.

Comment: Are you using this function to get script arguments ? If so, you should use getopts instead, which is very useful. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37786981/2394026) - [Tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

Comment: I decided to do it due to getopts doesn't allow flags composed bye two or more chars but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function menu () {
        while (($# >= 1))
        do
        key="$1"
        case $key in
                --supplierCode)
                supplier_code=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --vanID)
                van_id=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --vanIDp)
                van_idp=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --tgoID)
                tgo_id=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --tgoIDp)
                tgo_idp=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --company_name)
                company_name=$2
                shift
                ;;
                --ediFact)
                file_type=E
                ;;
                --webEdi)
                file_type=P
                ;;
                --PV)
                pv=1
                ;;
                --PT)
                pt=1
                ;;
                --help)

                exit
                ;;
        esac
        shift
        done
}
function error () {
        #Validations:
    is_valid=1
    if [ -z "$supplier_code" ]
        then
                echo "Missing supplierCode"
                is_valid=0
        fi

    if [ -z "$van_id" ]
        then
                echo "Missing vanID"
                is_valid=0
        fi
    if [ -z "$van_idp" ]
        then
                echo "Missing vanIDp"
                is_valid=0
        fi
    if [ -z "$tgo_id" ]
        then
                echo "Missing tgoID"
                is_valid=0
        fi
    if [ -z "$tgo_idp" ]
        then
                echo "Missing tgoIDp"
                is_valid=0
        fi
    if [ -z "$company_name" ]
        then
                echo "Missing company_name"
                is_valid=0
        fi
    if [ -z "$file_type" ]
        then
                echo "Missing ediFact or webEdi"
                is_valid=0
        fi
     if [ "$pv" -eq "0" ] && [ "$pt" -eq "0" ]
        then
                echo "Error: You have to use at least one of the flags --PV , --PT "
                is_valid=0
        fi
    if [ "$is_valid" -eq 1 ]
        then 
                printf "Here you could finally exit with code 2 (for user error), which we do.\n"
                exit 2
        fi

}
menu "$@"
error
```

Not the nicest edit of mine, but it should do what you indicated in the question, that is not exit early on first error, but going over all tests and then exit (with here the convention to return 2 as usage error code).

PS: My fingers also often type `echo` but my mind in most cases settles on `printf` as it is more versatile and portable for printing out "things" at the same time. It has format strings, and the options to echo vary across platforms.

Comment: Thanks this is a really creative solution, I am just going to construct a string composed by all the missing parameters, I appreciate the good sense of humor and the support, best regards.

Comment: It might be worth remembering that error messages should be written to standard error — redirect `>&2` after the `echo` or `printf` commands.